# Check two statements simultaneously

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, puppeteer

**The idea:**

I am building a bot to log into Instagram using `puppeteer`.
If the login is successful, nothing happens. When an error with ID `slfErrorAlert` occurs, the bot stops (because the LogIn was not successful).

**The problem:**

After pressing the LogIn button, the first and **afterwards** the second statement is checked.

However, it should be **checked at the same time** whether one or the other statement is true.

This could be the pseudo code:

`If (Login == true) continue;`

`else if (slfErrorAlert == visible) stop;`

**Current code snippet**

```
if ((await instagram.page.url() !== loginURL) || (await instagram.page.waitForSelector('#slfErrorAlert'))) {
    if (await instagram.page.url() !== loginURL) {
        log.info("LogIn successfull")
        log.info(instagram.page.url())
    }
    if (await instagram.page.waitForSelector('#slfErrorAlert')) {
        let loginMessage = await instagram.page.$eval('#slfErrorAlert', element => element.innerHTML)
        log.warn(`Client error - LogIn not possible: '${loginMessage}'`)
        await instagram.browser.close()
        return
    }
}
```

Full code is here: https://github.com/JueK3y/Instagram-automated-commenting/blob/main/public/src/js/instagram.js

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly, you want to test both async calls simultaneously. You can do that with the function `Promise.race`.

```
let promise1 = instagram.page.url();
let promise2 = instagram.page.waitForSelector('#slfErrorAlert');

Promise.race([promise1, promise2]).then((result) => {
  // do your checks here, either of the 2 promises was resolved
  // the result is either the one return from the first or second promise
})
```

For a detailed explanation and an extended example on how to use it, see [MDN web docs: Promise.race()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race)

Comment: Or, in the OP's style `const result = await Promise.race([p1,p2])`